# Placing PHP code in social locker PHP shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress. I am using the plugin social locker.

I have figured out how to display the shortcode via PHP:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="3071"]  My content Here [/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

However I want to display this button that will allow for a print popup in between there.

This code is:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'pdf_print_popup' ) ) pdf_print_popup(); ?>
```

So my question is can I do this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="3071"]  <?php if ( function_exists( 'pdf_print_popup' ) ) pdf_print_popup(); ?>   [/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

Comment: Probably better to ask on [wordpress.stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You have opening / closing PHP tags inside your echo statement.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
ob_start();

if ( function_exists( 'pdf_print_popup' ) ) {
    pdf_print_popup();
}

$content = ob_get_clean();

echo do_shortcode( '[sociallocker id="3071"]' . $content . '[/sociallocker]' ); ?>
```

You'd be better modifying `pdf_print_popup` to return instead of output a value as well removing the need for output buffering.

Comment: Social Locker was updated, and this code is'nt working correctly

Comment: The code demonstrates how to add PHP code to shortcode content. The plugin may have been updated but the theory remains.